# What is the difference between Front Controller and View Helper

Tags: design-patterns

They both seem to have the same purpose, which is to reduce complexity of front page code and to delegate more functions to the correct (business) tier. But what is the big difference between these 2? They seem to be doing pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front Controller is a controller pattern which provides a centralized controller for managing requests. Each client request must go through and be processed by the Front Controller first, no exceptions. All incoming data is delegated to front controller first. Useful for when your application has multiple entry points which you want to centralize through a single point for standardized processing.

View Helper on the other hand is a view layer. It simply arranges view components for the user and delegates processing to other business components so the view component doesn't have to contain any processing logic other than logic to present views. Example is if you need a shopping cart to persist through all the views, you store the cart on the View Helper which calls different views but you will always have access to the shopping cart.

They can both be used together.

Answer (score 1):

Front Controller is a controller layer pattern while View Helper is a view layer pattern. A Front Controller can use a View Helper.

Comment: Erm, can you be more specific?

Comment: I hope this helps http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/ViewHelper.htm This assumes that you know what responsibilities have controllers and views in mvc.